# como usar un Script en dos archivos html

Tags: javascript, html

Espero que me puedan ayudar o corregirme si estoy mal .. quisiera saber si es posible usar un mismo javascript en dos archivos html distintos, sin perder los valores de las variables que se generarían desde la primera pestaña al usar el script. o como puedo  hacer para que cuando se abra la segunda pestaña(segundo archivo html) utilizar esos valores que se generan en el script cuando se abre la primera pestaña(primer archivo html).

e intentado linker el mismo script desde los dos archivos html pero cuando se carga la segunda pestaña es como si se formateara las variables a las predefinidas.

Espero que me puedan dar ideas :)

Comment: Buenas bienvenido a **StackOverflow** en español por favor antes de preguntar primero ve [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y revisa también [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) edita tu pregunta y mejorarla para tener una respuesta que realmente te ayude.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar las variables de `localStorage` (te dejo informacion [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)) que con solo una vez asignado su valor puedes ocuparlo hasta en otro archivo JS, esto sirve para que el navegador guarde los datos y no se pierdan al recargar la pagina o cambiar de un html a otro.

***Ejemplo:***

```js
//Aqui asigna tu información en la variable localStorage
localStorage.setItem('miNombre', 'Juan')

var nombre = localStorage.getItem('miNombre')
console.log(nombre)
```

> Recuerda destruir el `localStorage`cuando ya no lo ocupes.